# How can I convert Arduino String to C string type?

Tags: c++, data-type

I got a `String` which as I understand is an Arduino object, and got some C++ code:

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <string.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x20,16,2); 

boolean borrar = false;
String IP;

void setup()
{
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

  while (Serial1.available()) { 

    char caracter = Serial1.read(); //Comprobamos el caracter 

    switch(caracter) {

    default:
                if (borrar) { 
                              IP = ""; 
                              lcd.clear();
                }

                lcd.print(caracter);
                delay(125);
                borrar = false;

                IP.concat(caracter);
                break;  

    case '\r':                
    case 0x0F:
    case 0x0A:  

                String res = "";
                borrar = true;
                int num= atoi(IP.c_str());
                if (num < 127) 
                  res="Clase A";
                if (num == 127) 
                  res="Direccion reservada";
                if (num > 127 && num < 192)
                  res="Clase B ";
                if (num >= 192 && num < 224)
                  res="Clase C ";
                if (num >= 224 && num < 240)
                  res="Clase D ";
                if (num >= 240 && num < 255)
                  res="Clase E ";
                break;  

  } //fin switch

}//serial disponible


}//fin programa
```

However, this won't compile because of this line:

```
int num= atoi(IP.c_str())
```

As IP is a **`String`** and such method works for **`string`**. How can I make it compatible (convert it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code could be improved by removing the use of `IP` string altogether, and directly calculating its numeric value while characters come in through `Serial1`:

```
...
boolean borrar = false;
int IP = 0;
...

void loop() {
  while (Serial1.available()) { 
    char caracter = Serial1.read(); //Comprobamos el caracter 
    switch(caracter) {

    // NOTE it is better to replace default by the list of all digits...    
    case '0':
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
                if (borrar) { 
                              IP = 0; 
                              lcd.clear();
                }

                lcd.print(caracter);
                delay(125);
                borrar = false;

                IP *= 10;
                IP += (int) (caracter - '0');
                break;  

    case '\r':                
    case 0x0F:
    case 0x0A:  

                String res = "";
                borrar = true;
                int num= IP;
                if (num < 127) 
                  res="Clase A";
                if (num == 127) 
                  res="Direccion reservada";
                if (num > 127 && num < 192)
                  res="Clase B ";
                if (num >= 192 && num < 224)
                  res="Clase C ";
                if (num >= 224 && num < 240)
                  res="Clase D ";
                if (num >= 240 && num < 255)
                  res="Clase E ";
                break;  

  } //fin switch

}//serial disponible

}//fin programa
```

This way would bring you 2 advantages:

1. a bit faster than working with `String`
2. no dynamic memory allocation/deallocation (`String` does a lot of these) which might lead your program to **[heap fragmentation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/763/im-using-too-much-ram-how-can-this-be-measured/787#787)** and eventually crash.

Note that I have not further refactored your code as I guessed it was just a snippet, not the complete code for your program. Otherwise, I would have performed further refinement like:

- remove `num` variable since it is the same as `IP` now
- replace `res` from `String` to `const char*` (to further reduce heap fragmentation due to `String` usage)

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
unsigned char z[100];
IP.getBytes(z, 100);
z[IP.length()] = 0;
int n = atoi(z);
```

To retrieve bytes inside the string. This assumes IP string's length is shorter than 100.

Comment: I tried and got:

`BluetoothLCD.cpp:51:35: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘unsigned char*’
BluetoothLCD.cpp:51:35: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void String::getBytes(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const’`

Comment: I have updated `char` to `unsigned char`

Comment: Something weird is going on, now I obtain:

`BluetoothLCD.cpp:53:33: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘const char*’
BluetoothLCD.cpp:53:33: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int atoi(const char*)’`

Comment: If it does not support, `IP.toCharArray(z, 100);` may be used.

Comment: How would code look like?

Comment: God, I think its done NOW

Answer (score 2):

Try updating to the latest version of the Arduino libraries/IDE.

The `c_str()` method was introduced to the Arduino String class quite recently, I believe. That line of code certainly works fine for me on Arduino IDE 1.0.5.

Comment: I'm using Linux IDE how would I do it?

Comment: @diegoaguilar - I think you'd have to manually update your Arduino core libraries. You can get them from GitHub: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino

Comment: Version 1.0.5 has c_str() it can be downloaded for linux from the official Arduino site: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software